# Visual Win32 (UI) style?

Tags: disassembly, assembly, c++

what is the following image is about ? Is it design using win32 (UI) ?
the following image contains functions are being output from a DLL. 
Can you help me to understand. 
Suggest me anything which will help me understand what these UI is all about?
[image]

EDiT: Where can i find tutorial / guide on sciter. Thanks

Comment: The fact that every name starts with "HTMLLayout" is a pretty good clue it is *not* (immediately) related to the Windows UI...

Comment: By the way, I disagree about the close votes. This is not asking about _reverse engineering a specific system_, it's asking for clues where to find more information about these functions. Big difference. This is not at all dissimilar to questions [like this one](https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/18514/).

Answer (score 4):

That looks to be [Sciter](https://sciter.com/), previous known as [HTMLLayout](https://terrainformatica.com/a-homepage-section/htmlayout/). That should lead you to the appropriate documentation necessary to study what those functions do.

**Source**: [The Google Machine](https://www.google.com/search?q=HTMLayout%20Master%20CSS)

Comment: I didn't know it at all. It is like these guys invented electron years before electron born

Comment: Where can i find tutorial / guide on sciter?